# Custom SMS text through web app

Tags: ios

I need to populate the SMS body depending on the button clicked in the iOS web app. 
Any way i can do this ?
something like :

a href="sms:1234" body = "hello world !">Send SMS /a

Comment: Are you using a UIWebView controller or is the web app in Safari?

Comment: a pure safari based web app with no access to Mail/SMS api ..

Answer (score 0):

The definitive answer can be found here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/SMSLinks/SMSLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH7-SW1